# Unzip a file from Buffer without saving file anywhere on disk in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

For my current project, I have zip files being sent to an API server via a base64 encoded string. I am looking to convert that string into a Buffer (or some sort of other object) and explode the ZIP file into an object structured in the same way as the files in the ZIP so I can push them to the cloud using file objects. I've read about ADM-ZIP and other similar tools but all of them seem to require a file on disk, unless I am just misunderstanding the documentation. I am looking to avoid saving files on a disk since this API runs in the cloud with a variable storage space.

Thank you for all of your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do manipulation with data without saving files in your case is `Streams` API in node.js. 
Look for the libs
`b64` - stream decoding of base64
`unzip-stream`- unziping files in stream

So your flow would be
Accept a request, create `ReadStream` from its data (base64) `pipe` it to `b64`, `pipe` it to `unzip-stream` and so on.